# R ggplot - Multiple lines with same color variable shows legends of only first line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the data (dt1) in  as follows:

```
dt1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(NA, 17179, 17180, 17181, 17182, 
17183, 17178, 17179, 17180, 17181, 17182, 17183), class = "Date"), 
    f = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y1 = c(68L, 
    43L, 99L, 53L, 12L, 20L, 29L, 49L, 68L, 15L, 71L, 88L), y2 = c(15L, 
    15L, 66L, 53L, 63L, 37L, 91L, 17L, 87L, 87L, 43L, 77L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")

       date f y1 y2
1  12-01-17 0 68 15
2  13-01-17 0 43 15
3  14-01-17 0 99 66
4  15-01-17 0 53 53
5  16-01-17 0 12 63
6  17-01-17 0 20 37
7  12-01-17 1 29 91
8  13-01-17 1 49 17
9  14-01-17 1 68 87
10 15-01-17 1 15 87
11 16-01-17 1 71 43
12 17-01-17 1 88 77
```

I now want to plot a multiple line chart with date on x-axis and y1 and y2 on y but represented by 2 different lines. But I also have the variable 'f' which I would like to use as color variable for both the lines. I write the following code:

```
ggplot(data = dt1) +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = y1, color = factor(f))) +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = y2, color = factor(f)))
```

But instead of 4 colors I get 2 colors for 4 lines i.e. 2 lines as blue and 2 lines as red and also in legends I only have the legends pertaining y1. I want to get 4 colors for all 4 lines and 4 item in legend box.

Comment: How do you get four colors from two options?

Comment: Why not use two colors for `f` and two different linetypes for `y1` and `y2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get 4 colours by crossing `f` variable with variable - if value comes from `y1` or `y2` column:

```
dt1 %>%
  gather(key, value, y1:y2) %>%
  unite('f', f:key, sep = '_') %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = date,
    y = value,
    color = f
  )) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to ask if we can do the same data transformation by data.table as tidyverse package isn't available somehow?

Comment: Yes. You can do it as following:
`dt1 <-melt(
  dt1,
  id.vars = c('date', 'f'),
  measure.vars = c('y1', 'y2')
)[, f := paste(f, variable, sep = '_')]

ggplot(
  data = dt1,
  aes(
    x = date,
    y = value,
    color = f
  )) +
  geom_line()
`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use four colors for two groups. Instead, use two colors and two linetypes:

```
x <- c("y1" = "solid", "y2" = "dashed")

ggplot(data = dt1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = y1, color = factor(f), linetype = "y1")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = y2, color = factor(f), linetype = "y2")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = x)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I wanted to know if I want to format the linetype legend, how can I do that? I can format the factor(f) legend using scale_color_manual.

Comment: The `scale_linetype_manual` you see in the code can be used to format the legend.

Answer (score 0):

You get the expected behavior - first draw lines for y1 values where the color depend on the factor (0,1) for each row then draw lines for y2 values where the color depend on the factor (0,1) for each row.

Reducing the case to the first two records for instance: what is the requirement to assign colors to y1 and y2 who have f value of zero? Do you want to assign color 0 to one and color 1 to the other (in which case you don't need this info in each row) or do you want some kind of line that will alternate color (so here both lines would be of color 0 for the first two rows, then if a row has factor 1 both lines would be of color 1)?

if you want to one color per line, hardcode in the color parameter instead of using the row factor

```
dt1 <- data.frame(x = c("01/01/19","01/02/19","01/03/19"), f = as.factor(c(1,1,0)), y1 = c(6,8,7), y2 = c(10,12,14))
dt1$x <- as.Date(dt1$x, "%m/%d/%y")

ggplot(data = dt1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y2, color = "red"))  + 
               geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y1, color = "blue"))
```

if you want to alternate colors on y1 and y2, this is what it can look like using points (lines seem more tricky)

```
dt1 <- data.frame(x = c("01/01/19","01/02/19","01/03/19"), f = as.factor(c(1,1,0)), y1 = c(6,8,7), y2 = c(10,12,14))
dt1$x <- as.Date(dt1$x, "%m/%d/%y")

ggplot(data = dt1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2, color = factor(f)))  + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y1, color = factor(f)))
```

Comment: Hi there. While a detailed answer is grood, it can be made better by using the provided data to provide a solution containing code(too).

Comment: thanks for the feedback @NelsonGon I tried to add some code to illustrate. The second case with lines seems a bit tricky so I'd rather confirm before trying it seriously.